# How to call multiple API and subscribe in angular 6?

Tags: angular, request, observable

In my app, to call all the `POST` request I have used a `service`.

When I get a **specific** code **(E.x : 401)** from the server, I call an API to fetch new token.

Till the another token is received, if there's any other API call from, I store all those requests in an array. It may be **n** requests. For now assume there are 3 API call while the call for newToken API is in progress.

Once I get a new token I have to pass that in all the subsequent API's. Now I have to execute all the pending API requests and give data to their respective calls.

**Code Example :**

**api.service.ts**

```
POST(URL , param){
   return new Observable<any>(observer => {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

  let options = {
    headers: headers
  };

  this.http.post(URL, param, options)
        .subscribe(data => {
          var apiRes: any = data;                                       
          this.inValidSession();
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();              
  }
  ......

  //  For execute pending request I have set this 

  for (let i = 0; i < this.queue.length; i++) {                          
        this.REPOST(this.queue[i].param, this.queue[i].url).subscribe((queueResponse) => {             
          observer.next(queueResponse);
          observer.complete();
          this.queue.shift();                      
       });
   }
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getUserData();        
    this.getProductData();
}

getUserData(){
   this.apiService.post({},'/apiName').subscribe((response) => {
       console.log(response);
   })
}

getProductData(){
   this.apiService.post({},'/apiName2').subscribe((response) => {
       console.log(response);
   })
}
```

Issue is , when I execute all pending API's, I get data in the console. But not `subscribe` from service file to respective `.ts` file's function.

Note: I get subscribed data in only one function not each. In other words, I get both API res in `getProductData()` function. I don't know why.

Please help me if any one has solution.

Comment: `forkJoin()` will be helpful to make multiple calls at a time

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT I have tried to use that and I got data in console in a form of array. But then my `subscribe` is not working. That is the problem.

Comment: Also it will useful when I directly call from `ts`. But I have used services for reuse the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
forkJoin()
```

To handle multiple calls at the same time, where you can call multiple `request` and after subscribing you will get an `array` of resoponse.

eg

```
    forkJoin(Service1.call1, 
     Service2.call2)
    .subscribe(([call1Response, call2Response]) => {
```

Where service1 and service2 are service which have function ccall1 and call2 , that are having `return` type  `Observable`

You can find more [Here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: I have already tried to use `forkJoin` but it returns all data in a single time. And then I cann't return value to `ts`. I mean when I used `forkJoin` my `subscribe` is not working.

Comment: you can just return forkJoin(Service1.call1, Service2.call2) or if you are subscribing to it then you should return the result as an observable : forkJoin(Service1.call1, Service2.call2).subscribe(() => //return new observable containing the result )

Answer (score 3):

**Easy Method**

use forkjoin()

```
public sample(): Observable<any[]>
{

let call1=this.http.get(this._url+'/v1/sample1')

let call2=this.http.get(this._url+'/v1/sample2')

let call3=this.http.get(this._url+'/v1/sample3')

return forkJoin([call1, call2,call3]);

}
```

Comment: thanks asifali. really it is easy method .i've used in my code. and working fine

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` lib from `rxjs`

```
import { zip } from "rxjs";

myFun() {    
   zip(service.api1, service.api2)
       .subscribe(([response1, response2]) => {
          console.log(response1);
          console.log(response2);
    })
}
```