# Angular wait for multiple http requests to complete and then fire the last one

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 4 http requests. Three receives lookup values while the 4th one gets actual form data.

They go like this:

```
   let medicalData = this.data.getCodes('medical').subscribe((data: {}) => {
     console.log('med');
       this.Medical = data;
        });
   let delayData = this.data.getCodes('delay').subscribe((data: {}) => {
    console.log('del');
          this.Delays = data;
           });
   let disabilityData = this.data.getCodes('disability').subscribe((data: {}) => {
    console.log('dis');
            this.Disability = data;
             });
   let districtData = this.data.getCodes('district').subscribe((data: {}) => {
    console.log('dist');
              this.District = data;
               });
```

How can I make the 4th get request wait till the first three requests are complete ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use `forkJoin` to achieve the desired result. `forkJoin` waits for all obesrvables to complete before emitting a value. Example:

```js
forkJoin(
  this.data.getCodes('medical'),
  this.data.getCodes('delay'),
  this.data.getCodes('disability'),
  this.data.getCodes('district'),
).subscribe(([medicalData, delayData, disabilityData, districtData]) => {
  this.Medical = medicalData;
  this.Delays = delayData;
  this.Disability = disabilityData;
  this.District = districtData;

  // make your last http request here.
});
```

Comment: In my case I have used service to call `POST` req , Now If I use `forkJoin` then how could I subscribe API response to my `.ts` file ?

Comment: In that case I would use a `switchMap` so that you can return the Observable. It would look similar to this: `forkJoin(/* ... */).switchMap(([a, b, c, d]) => { /* ... */ return this.http.post('/url', data); })`

Comment: I have a same issue like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002461/how-to-call-multiple-api-and-subscribe-in-angular-6/53002664#53002664

Comment: Yes that should do what you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: No not yet but I'll try and also I have some ways to do that. Thanks for your reply... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use forkJoin

```
let medicalData = this.data.getCodes('medical');
let delayData = this.data.getCodes('delay');
let disabilityData = this.data.getCodes('disability')
Observable.forkJoin([medicalData, delayData, disabilityData]).subscribe((responses)=>{
    // responses is an array of responses for the individual observables
    // Execute the code you want to run after the three observables here
});
```

Comment: In my case I have used service to call POST req , Now If I use forkJoin then how could I subscribe API response to my .ts file ?

Comment: can you elaborate? do you have multiple post requests?

Comment: Please check this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002461/how-to-call-multiple-api-and-subscribe-in-angular-6/53002664#53002664

Comment: Have to got issue ?

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, however quick question. where would you handle the individual error returns for this ? and does the execute only fire once every request has returned?

Comment: Depending on the angular version you can use 
Observable.forkJoin(observableArray).catch(error =>{ 
//execute error handling 
}.subscribe((responses)=>{
    // success function
});
for older versions and 
Observable.forkJoin(observableArray).pipe(catchError(error => {
// error handeling function
})).subscribe((responses)=>{
    // success function
});
for newer versions.