# How can I create an async/promise function with for loop & APIs in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am struggling to make a function return data AFTER, and only after it's done making all the API calls and for loop.

```
getListingsImages(sessionID, mlsSearchCriteria){

      this.http.get(this.laconiaBaseURL + "mls/search/" + sessionID + "?" +queryString).subscribe((data)=>{

        listings = data['data'];

         for (let listing of listings) {

          postData.listingImageURL = imageBaseURL + listing.firstImage;
          postData.listingPrice = this.formatter.format(listing.ListPrice).toString();
          postData.listingMLSID = listing.listingKey;
          postData.listingAddress = listing.FullAddress;

          this.http.post(this.imageParserBaseURL, postData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((data)=>{

            this.slides.push({
              data: data,
              type: "image",
              slideHeader: null,
              duration: 10
            });

          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Notice how I have two http calls, I want to wait until both the listings get obtained, the for loop iterates and posts the data. **this.slides** is just a global variable at the moment.

I tried using callbacks and I just don't get them quite well, all the examples don't really assimilate too well to my case.

How can I make my code await for completion of of both API calls and For loop?

Comment: You cannot make your function block (avoid returning) until after the asynchronous actions complete. Instead, make your function return a Promise which will only resolve after the asynchronous actions complete.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051473/angular-wait-for-multiple-http-requests-to-complete-and-then-fire-the-last-one

Comment: @StriplingWarrior in Angular, it's recommended to do things with observables instead of promises. In this case the post-calls should be stored in an array and then forkjoin them.

Comment: @ShamPooSham: Observables are certainly more flexible and powerful than Promises, and Angular uses them for a reason. In practice, Observables add a whole new layer of complexity whose value usually only arises in a handful of corner cases. I've found that most of the time it's better to quickly translate them to promises and use them to set state. For someone who's struggling to understand basic async workflows, Promises are a big enough concept to swallow as it is. Plus, the question's title specifically asks for an `async`/`Promise` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to translate the observables into promises, and then use a typical async/await pattern, like so:

```
async getListingsImages(sessionID, mlsSearchCriteria) {
  const data = await lastValueFrom(this.http.get(this.laconiaBaseURL + "mls/search/" + sessionID + "?" +queryString));
  listings = data['data'];
  let postDatas = listings.map(listing => Object.assign({}, postData, {
      listingImageURL: imageBaseURL + listing.firstImage,
      listingPrice: this.formatter.format(listing.ListPrice).toString(),
      listingMLSID: listing.listingKey,
      listingAddress: listing.FullAddress
    });
  let posts = postDatas
    .map(postData => this.http.post(this.imageParserBaseURL, postData, {responseType: 'text'}))
    .map(obs => lastValueFrom(obs));
  const results = await Promise.all(posts);
  const newSlides = results.map(data =>{
          data: data,
          type: "image",
          slideHeader: null,
          duration: 10
        });
  this.slides.push(... newSlides);
}
```

This makes some assumptions about acceptable behavior. For example:

- you want the values added to `this.slides` to be in the same order that they are returned in the first request's data
- you're okay with waiting until all of the results come back before updating `this.slides`
- you don't need to cancel requests
- you don't need to throttle or limit the concurrent requests being made to `imageParserBaseURL`

If you need more advanced behavior, this will require tweaking. You may even need to return an Observable instead of a Promise.